# How to determine the presence of an I18n namespace in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I am trying to write a custom exception handler for the I18n gem that will override the default "translation missing" error and throw noisy exceptions for special cases such as when the locale is missing and when a top-level namespace is missing.  Missing locale is just a matter of checking if `available_locales.include?(locale)`, but how do I see if a namespace is defined?  Essentially, I want the following functionality:

```
def caption
  begin
    I18n.t("event.welcome", :locale => :en)
  rescue MissingNamespace # should be thrown when "event" doesn't exist as a key under :en, (I18n would normally overspecify and say that "event.welcome" as a full key doesn't exist"
    "Namespace is missing"
  rescue
    #other stuff
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this?  Or can I only lookup on the basis of a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the trick:

```
module I18n
  def namespace_missing?(locale, key)
    namespace = key.split(".")[0] # assuming you want the top level namespace
    !backend.send(:translations)[locale][namespace] # this presupposes locale exists
  end
end
```

... and then you can throw that in your exception handler